# How can I get day instead of simple text value in Chartbar. - Flutter

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to pass day in text widget but it is not working and show me simple text widget string. But in console day is show.
**Passing day from here.**

```
 List<Map<String, Object>> get groupedTransactionValues {
        return List.generate(7, (index) {
          final weekDay = DateTime.now().subtract(
            Duration(days: index),
          );
    
          var totalSum = 0.0;
          for (var i = 0; i < recentTransactions.length; i++) {
            if (recentTransactions[i].date.day == weekDay.day &&
                recentTransactions[i].date.month == weekDay.month &&
                recentTransactions[i].date.year == weekDay.year) {
              totalSum += recentTransactions[i].amount;
            }
          }
          return {
            'day': DateFormat.E().format(weekDay).substring(0, 3),
            "amount": totalSum,
          };
        });
      }
```

**Problem is in here.**

```
 children: groupedTransactionValues.map((data) {
              return ChartBars(
                data['day'] as String ,
                data['amount'] as double,
                totalSpending == 0.0
                    ? 0.0
                    : (data['amount'] as double) / totalSpending,
              );
            }).toList()
```

**Console output:**
I/flutter (28610): [{day: Mon, amount: 0.0}, {day: Sun, amount: 0.0}, {day: Sat, amount: 0.0}, {day: Fri, amount: 0.0}, {day: Thu, amount:0.0}, {day: Wed, amount: 0.0}, {day: Tue, amount:0.0}]

Here is complete code

```
 import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
    
    import '../models/transaction.dart';
    import './chart_bar.dart';
    
    class Chart extends StatelessWidget {
      final List<Transation> recentTransactions;
    
      Chart(this.recentTransactions);
    
      List<Map<String, Object>> get groupedTransactionValues {
        return List.generate(7, (index) {
          final weekDay = DateTime.now().subtract(
            Duration(days: index),
          );
    
          var totalSum = 0.0;
          for (var i = 0; i < recentTransactions.length; i++) {
            if (recentTransactions[i].date.day == weekDay.day &&
                recentTransactions[i].date.month == weekDay.month &&
                recentTransactions[i].date.year == weekDay.year) {
              totalSum += recentTransactions[i].amount;
            }
          }
          return {
            'day': DateFormat.E().format(weekDay).substring(0, 3),
            "amount": totalSum,
          };
        });
      }
    
      double get totalSpending {
        return groupedTransactionValues.fold(0.0, (sum, element) {
          return sum + (element['amount'] as double);
        });
      }
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        print(groupedTransactionValues);
        return Card(
          elevation: 6,
          margin: EdgeInsets.all(20),
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
            children: groupedTransactionValues.map((data) {
              return ChartBars(
                data['day'] as String ,
                data['amount'] as double,
                totalSpending == 0.0
                    ? 0.0
                    : (data['amount'] as double) / totalSpending,
              );
            }).toList(),
          ),
        );
      }
    }

**Here is char_bar.dart file.**
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ChartBars extends StatelessWidget {
  final String label;
  final double spendingAmount;
  final double spendingPctOfTotal;

  ChartBars(this.label, this.spendingAmount, this.spendingPctOfTotal);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Text("\$${spendingAmount.toStringAsFixed(0)}"),
        SizedBox(height: 4),
        Container(
            height: 60,
            width: 10,
            child: Stack(
              children: [
                Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    border: Border.all(
                      color: Colors.green,
                      width: 1.0,
                    ),
                    color: Color.fromRGBO(220, 220, 220, 1),
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                  ),
                ),
                FractionallySizedBox(
                  heightFactor: spendingPctOfTotal,
                  child: Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.brown[300]),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            )),
        SizedBox(height: 4),
        Text("day")
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If im reading this right you want to be displaying your var `label` in the `Text` widget.

You are currently sending it a `String` of `"day"`

Try changing your `Text` widget call to `Text(label)`

That should give you the desired effect